# Rails console won't load, "Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.0.0.beta3) ruby"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I typed in Rails console to begin working and received the error below:

```
MacBook-Pro:blog agreiner$ rails console
/Users/agreiner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.0.0.beta3) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /Users/agreiner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler 1.1.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:161:in `start'
from /Users/agreiner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler 1.1.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `block in resolve'
from /Users/agreiner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `catch'
from /Users/agreiner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `resolve'
from /Users/agreiner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `resolve'
from /Users/agreiner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler 1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
from /Users/agreiner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:161:in `requested_specs'
from /Users/agreiner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
from /Users/agreiner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler 1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
from /Users/agreiner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
from /Users/agreiner/blog/config/boot.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/agreiner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/agreiner/.rvm/rubies/ruby 1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require' from >script/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

I started working with Rails a few days ago so my ability to analyze the errors is limited to my ability to google. I haven't found anything regarding the `Could not find gem 'rails(=3.0.0beta3) ruby`

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` before it?

Comment: You only started a few days ago but youre working with Rails 3.0.0 beta? Anyway, try to run `bundle install` and if that doesnt work, edit your `Gemfile` to get the last version of rails, just remove the 3.0.0beta version from the rails gem include

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the rails gem was installed at one point, but then only partially uninstalled, or is installed, but in an unexpected location. The first step is to try reinstalling. I'm not sure if you're using the system ruby, or one installed via rvm/ruby-build, so it's hard to give more advice than this.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find your rails gem.
Try first:

gem install rails